# Code obfuscation using Eclipse IDE in Android

Tags: android, obfuscation

Provide me the steps to obfuscate an Android application from Eclipse IDE.
Is Proguard.jar best for this obfuscation purpose or do we have better obfuscator?

Comment: Why do you want to obfuscate your application? Compiling into source code will essentially do just that by making your application bytecode.

Comment: @Chris: http://code.google.com/p/smali/

Comment: @Christopher: can you explain?  I do not understand how obfuscating the code would help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just in the last couple days, they've given instructions on how to do this in the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29)

Comment: And yes, the benefits of it reach far beyond the size stuff that's being mentioned. It will make your decompiled bytecode more difficult to reverse engineer. Certainly not impossible, but it will replace your descriptively-named variables and functions with meaningless strings.